# In Gnome, why does starting a favorited sandboxed application create a new icon on the dash?

Tags: gnome, gui, sandbox

I think this is something that's easier to show than tell.

[image: New Icon]

So you see in this image of my dash, I clicked on the Tor icon with the gradient background, but it actually opened the application using a new icon on the dash. Kind of annoying.

This happens when altering the .desktop file on the application to open it with Firejail, Bubblewrap, or another sandboxing application like this:

`Exec=/usr/bin/firejail /usr/lib/firefox/firefox`

So why does this happen and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

Found this somewhat obscure problem without a solution I could find online. So figured I'd post it here.

So what appears to be causing this is the change of `$HOSTNAME` that is a common in sandboxing applications. If the `$HOSTNAME` is different from the user opening the application, it will make a new icon for the application.

While I gave an example using Firejail for simplicity's sake､ I actually use Bubblewrap. I'm sure the solution will be similar in Firejail. I would love if anyone could provide the answer for it for completion's sake though.

So in Bubblewrap, you would basically just remove these lines:

```
--unshare-uts \
--hostname FIREFOX \
```

Alternatively, you could actually still unshare-uts as long as the `$HOSTNAME` remains the same. (I'm not sure if this would provide any additional protection though.) For example:

```
--unshare-uts \
--hostname "${HOSTNAME}" \
```

Another alternative is you could actually change your `$HOSTNAME` before starting the program. `export HOSTNAME=FIREFOX` did not work for me. But `hostnamectl hostname FIREFOX` did. The problem with this is that your `$HOSTNAME` will remain the same as long as the program is running. Which may break other programs or cause other issues

```
hostnamectl hostname FIREFOX

bwrap \
[...]
--unshare-uts \
--hostname FIREFOX \
[...]
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox

hostnamectl hostname "${HOSTNAME}"
```

I have not tested this, but in theory, you should be able to run a script in the background that would sleep for maybe 5 seconds, waiting for the application to start, then set the `$HOSTNAME` back. Unsure of any problems this might cause though.

Obviously, this is all up to you whether the solution for this minor inconvenience makes sense for you and your situation/"threat model".